# Como passar informações a uma variável javascript

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownPress, false);
var valoresDigitados = [];

function keyDownPress(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode;
  valoresDigitados.push(String.fromCharCode(keyCode));
}

setInterval(function(){ 
 window.alert(valoresDigitados.join(""));
}, 3000);
</script>
```

Pretendo passar o `valoresDigitados.push(String.fromCharCode(keyCode));` para uma variável e de seguida enviar para um arquivo em tempo real.

Como poderei fazer?

Comment: Podes explicar melhor _"e de seguida enviar para um arquivo em tempo real"_? queres gravar no servidor? qual é a funcionalidade que precisa de gravar letra a letra num ficheiro? (explica melhor para percebermos o que procuras)

Comment: Não sei se te recordas que fiz um sistema semelhante e que me ajudaste, enviar a variavel para uma outra pagina em tempo real, é isso que queria dizer.

Comment: essa pergunta precisa de mais informaçao..